# How to add static route via docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to add static route to remote network with is accessible only via VPN connection is made on host machine.

In docker compose I have added definition of additional network for that purpose - beside default one:

```
networks:
    net0:
        driver: bridge
        name: net0
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
                  gateway: 172.20.0.1
    net1_vpn:
        driver: bridge
        name: net1_vpn
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.30.30.0/24
                  gateway: 172.30.30.1
```

to each defined service in docker-compose i added:

```
cap_add:    
   - NET_ADMIN
```

to allow network modification.

Dockerfile include installation of iproute2 package - as ip command is required.

And now, when I execute from inside containers (as root) or via `docker exec -u root` command: `ip route add 192.168.0.0/16 via 172.30.30.2` route is added and everything works fine. But when i include same command in docker-compose file like this:

```
command: ip route add 192.168.0.0/16 via 172.30.30.2
```

or in dockerfile as

```
USER root
RUN ip route add 192.168.0.0/16 via 172.30.30.2
```

given docker container wont start, or throw error "Operation not permitted" on build phase

- I already have tried multiple ways of same command to run
- verified if in all cases ip command is present and is executed as root inside container
- review documentation and few dozens of similar topics that I could find

What I do not understand right now is what is differences between running same command from dockerfile/docker-compose vs calling docker exec execution or from inside container - as those should behave in the same way.

Also is there any proper/recommended way for setting custom routing inside docker container - as this topic is somehow "uncommon".

Answer (score 0):

It's probably late, but I'll add answer for others.

1. Case with docker-compose.yml

   Providing `command` in the docker-compose.yml means that you override the default `command` that starts your service(s). Since you don't start it yourself later, the container will stop.
2. Case with Dockerfile

   When you add `RUN ip route add...` to your Dockerfile, it means you are trying to add a route while building the image. And this is not equivalent to case #1. Equivalent will be adding `CMD ip route add...` in the Dockerfile. But again, you need to add the start command for your service. You can get solve this(running multiple commands) by using an `entrypoint` or running bash script as a command.
   In your case, this version probably produced an "Operation not allowed" error. I'm not sure why docker doesn't allow static routes to be configured during image build.
3. Running command with docker-compose vs dockerfile vs exec inside container

> What I do not understand right now is what is differences between running same command from dockerfile/docker-compose vs calling docker exec execution or from inside container - as those should behave in the same way.

There are differences. Short, you are running the same command in different phases (as a start command for image/container, during the image build, during the the container running phase)